# Неккоректная установка Timestamp в базу Oracle при работе из SpringBoot + java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

При создании записи в базу данных, должен срабатывать триггер,

```sql
BEFORE INSERT
ON base.LOG_CRITICAL_ERRORS_NC 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.ERR_UPDATED := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  :NEW.DATE_RCV :=SYSDATE;
END LOG_CRITICAL_ERRORS_NC_BIO;
```

так вот,

```sql
  :NEW.DATE_RCV :=SYSDATE;
```

эта команда создает дату корректно

```sql
  :NEW.ERR_UPDATED := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

**отстает ровно на час !!!**

Почему ?

вот поле сущности

```java
 /**Дата и время возникновения ошибки*/
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Column(name = "ERR_UPDATED", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime errUpdated;
```

если запись выполняется из командной строки plsql, тогда все корректно записывается

Вот вывод Hibernate

```java
2019-11-26 09:31:59.413 DEBUG 10008 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        log_critical_errors_nc
        (date_rcv, err_log_id, err_msg_id, err_text, err_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        log_critical_errors_nc
        (date_rcv, err_log_id, err_msg_id, err_text, err_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-11-26 09:31:59.415 TRACE 10008 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2019-10-12T15:46:29.000000099]
2019-11-26 09:31:59.416 TRACE 10008 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [8422]
2019-11-26 09:31:59.417 TRACE 10008 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1101161]
2019-11-26 09:31:59.419 TRACE 10008 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Запись сделана из тестового модуля для условия : если status > 10 && status != 15]
2019-11-26 09:31:59.420 TRACE 10008 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [473]
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:3006', transport: 'socket'
```

Здесь при вставке, **Hibernate** даже не упоминает поле **ERR_UPDATED**

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP,
       DBTIMEZONE,
       SESSIONTIMEZONE
  FROM DUAL;
```

**вывод**

```sql
SYSTIMESTAMP                    DBTIMEZONE,         SESSIONTIMEZONE
26.11.19 10:28:22,092000000 +03:00  +03:00    26.11.19 10:28:22,092000000   EUROPE/MINSK
```

На сервере, в настройках ОС, указан тот же часовой пояс и расположение, что
и на клиентской машине.

Кроме того, модуль написанный на **delphi** не имеет таких проблем и дата устанавливается корректно.

Как и посоветовали мне, мы поменяли

```sql
 :NEW.ERR_UPDATED := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

на

```sql
 :NEW.ERR_UPDATED := SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Запись даты создается корректно, но почему ?

> TIMESTAMP
>
> Хранит 4-байтное целое число, равное количеству секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года по усреднённому времени Гринвича (т.е. нулевой часовой пояс, точка отсчёта часовых поясов). При получении из базы отображается с учётом часового пояса. Часовой пояс может быть задан в операционной системе, глобальных настройках MySQL или в конкретной сессии.
>
> Запомните, что сохраняется всегда количество секунд по UTC (универсальное координированное время, солнечное время на меридиане Гринвича), а не по локальному часовому поясу.

Но вот данное замечание было касательно MySQL, справедливо ли оно и для Oracle ?

Может быть действительно база  данных выполняла преобразование числа секунд,  учетом настроек текущего **`connection`** и брала данные о часовом поясе из драйвера JDBC ?

И как быть с другими модулями на delphi, которые работали со старой записью ?

У кого есть идеи, как это исправить ?

Comment: У вас БД в другом часовом поясе стоит. Надо  SYSTIMESTAMP.

Comment: я выше дописал проверку часового пояса. Где нужно ставить SYSTIMESTAMP ?

Answer (score 3):

> отстает ровно на час!!! Почему?

Потому, что всё, что начинается с префиксом:

- `SYS*` - это системное время машины, где установлена БД
- `CURRENT_*` это локальное время сессии

Если с системным временем всё вроде понятно, то определение времени сессии "длинная история", включающая: ОС и её установки, клиентский фрэймворк, вплоть до определения геокоординат по спутникам.
Эта история заканчивается, явно или неявно, банальной установкой часового пояса сессии через `set time_zone`.

```sql
select systimestamp systs, current_timestamp sests from dual;

SYSTS                                SESTS                              
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------
2019-11-26 12:25:43,133441000 +03:00 2019-11-26 12:25:43,133447000 EUROPE/MINSK

alter session set time_zone = 'Asia/Yekaterinburg';

SYSTS                                SESTS                              
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------
2019-11-26 12:26:27,067530000 +03:00 2019-11-26 14:26:27,067535000 ASIA/YEKATERINBURG
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего примера можно увидеть что есть разница между результатом вручную (через PL SQL девелопер) и тем инсертом что производит ваша программа.

А раз так то у вас вероятно есть расхождения в параметрах сессий которые открывает ваша программа и среда. У меня была похожая ситуация с точностью до наоборот - был сдвиг по времени именно в среде и я решал это так:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE ...
```

В вашем случае проблема где то на стороне Java, которая по умолчанию берет ТЗ в соответствии с той в которой запущена JVM. Соответственно вы можете попробовать поменять ТЗ для JVM, а можете написать в ваших DAO что то вроде:

```
session = sessionFactory.withOptions()
.jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
.openSession();
```

Это эквивалент ALTER SESSION для orm, различие может быть в том как вы работаете с hibernate и соотвественно вместо UTC - должна быть ТЗ вашей БД.

О том как можно настроить TimeZone в спринг-буте можно почитать [здесь](https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-time-zone-configuration-using-hibernate/) (см. Hibernate Tip).

Comment: использовали JDC_template и пытались изменить timeZone, эффекта не получили

Comment: так как используется spring boot, то даже если бы такой вариант работал, много нужно было бы переделать, и работать только через hibernate, напрямую

Comment: по поводу JVM приложение будет где-то развертываться и не очень удобно, если нужно будет дополнительно указывать в документации, чтобы администратор настраивал еще свойства JVM и вообще то я сомневаюсь, что это вообще нужно, что проблема в настройках JVM

Comment: еще как может быть в JVM, возможно ваша старая версия просто не знает о том что у нас в стране время переносили

Comment: к слову опускаться до hibernate не нужно, зачастую достаточно создания бина в конфиг файле, либо строчки в yaml, постараюсь найти для вас подходящую

Comment: Добавил информацию в ответ. Попробуйте, поэкспериментировать с разными TZ, если эффекта не будет - стоит начать думать в сторону БД. Убедитесь еще что у вас используется диалект Oracle.